# MySql Procedure SCD Type Facing issue

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a generic procedure and want to use it for multiple tables to implement same type of SCD type 2.

...

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSCDType2 (
    IN source_table_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN target_table_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN key_columns VARCHAR(255) -- Comma-separated list of key columns
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE current_key_column VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE key_column_value VARCHAR(255);

    -- Separate schema and table names
    SET @source_schema_name := SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_table_name, '.', 1);
    SET @source_table_name := SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_table_name, '.', -1);
    SET @target_schema_name := SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_table_name, '.', 1);
    SET @target_table_name := SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_table_name, '.', -1);

    -- Loop through key columns
    SET done = FALSE;
    REPEAT
        -- Get the next key column
        SET current_key_column := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(key_columns, ',', 1), ',', -1);
        SET key_columns := SUBSTRING(key_columns, LENGTH(current_key_column) + 2);

        -- Check if there are more key columns
        IF LENGTH(key_columns) = 0 THEN
            SET done = TRUE;
        END IF;

        -- Execute dynamic SQL to retrieve key column value
        SET @key_select := CONCAT('SELECT ', current_key_column, ' INTO @key_column_value FROM ', source_table_name, ' LIMIT 1;');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @key_select;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        -- Check if the record already exists in the target table
        SET @count_query := CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @count FROM ', target_table_name, ' WHERE ', current_key_column, ' = @key_column_value;');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @count_query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        IF @count > 0 THEN
            -- Update existing record in the target table
            SET @update_query := CONCAT('UPDATE ', target_table_name, ' SET NX_UPDATE_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, version_ind = 0 WHERE ', current_key_column, ' = @key_column_value;');
            PREPARE stmt FROM @update_query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        ELSE
            -- Insert new record into target table
            SET @insert_query := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', target_table_name, ' SELECT * FROM ', source_table_name, ' WHERE ', current_key_column, ' = @key_column_value;');
            PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to add sample data as well as well i was trying to achieve

```
Sample Data Example 

Example: Default value for now is delete flag is 0 
I have a record in source as below 
Insurance_SK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,INSURANCE_CREATE_DATE , INSURANCE_UPDATE_DATE,version_indicator,delete_flag
1,ah,aj,aj,ajja,jojo,jkkj,2024-02-20,9999-12-31,1,0

and target it should be loaded as 
Insurance_SK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,INSURANCE_CREATE_DATE , INSURANCE_UPDATE_DATE,version_ind,Is_Delete
1,ah,aj,aj,ajja,jojo,jkkj,2024-02-20,9999-12-31,1,0

Second scenario when we got update and insert new record 

I have 2 records in source as below 
Insurance_SK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,INSURANCE_CREATE_DATE , INSURANCE_UPDATE_DATE,version_indicator,delete_flag
2,ah,aj,aj,ajja,jojo,hgfrtavi,2024-02-20,9999-12-31,1,0
3,Ins,paid,aj,ajja,jojo,hgfrtavi,2024-02-20,9999-12-31,1,0

and target it should be loaded as 
Insurance_SK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,INSURANCE_CREATE_DATE , INSURANCE_UPDATE_DATE,version_ind,Is_Delete
1,ah,aj,aj,ajja,jojo,jkkj,2024-02-20,2024-02-21,0,0
2,ah,aj,aj,ajja,jojo,hgfrtavi,2024-02-20,9999-12-31,1,0
3,Ins,paid,aj,ajja,jojo,hgfrtavi,2024-02-20,9999-12-31,1,0
```

Is there anything i am missing in the code as approx 30 records are getting loaded out of 20k records and something is messing up and unable to find

Comment: What does SCD stand for?

Comment: Looks like much of your code could be simplified by using `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: Hi @Barmar: Scd type is for ETL. we are maintaining historical record to expire and insert if any update else insert

Comment: SCD -- Slow changing dimension CDC type 2 change capture data

Comment: This is some kind of log of all the changes, and you have a separate row for each value in the CSV?

Comment: Hi @Barmar : We have source as two tables source and target. while loading the data from source we are maintaining historical records

Comment: Consider loading the relevant source table data into a temporary table first. Then, perform a LEFT JOIN between the target table and this temporary table to find  records that need to be updated (existing ones) and inserted (new ones). Bulk Processing Instead of Row-by-Row: Process updates and inserts in batches rather than row-by-row to improve performance. This is particularly important for large datasets.

Comment: @BillKarwin: STOP means ?

Comment: There are problems with making a single procedure that intends to handle a variety of tables and columns. For instance, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, because you are concatenating unknown table and column identifiers together.

Comment: Also you are mixing up local variables (the type you `DECLARE`) with MySQL user variables (the type with the `@` sigil). These are not the same variables, even when the name matches.

Comment: If your table has a compound set of key columns, your code still checks the columns one by one, which could either copy overlapping sets, or else miss some rows.

Comment: Basically, by making this procedure "generic," you are over-complicating the code and it will break in several edge cases. It would be simpler to develop and simpler to test if you do not make it generic, but make one procedure for each table you need to copy, so you don't have to build dynamic SQL statements. Instead, code the SQL statements as fixed statements.

Comment: Also you should learn about [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).